# Proxy object for lazy initialization

Tags: python, lazy-initialization, proxy-classes

Are there any ready-to-use Python module that provides an easy to use proxy object that only initializes the "real" object when really needed?

Ideally I'm looking for a transparent implementation so that code dealing with this proxy object does not need to be aware that it is not the actual object.

I want to use it like this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Example initialized")

lazy = Proxy(Example)
print(isinstance(lazy, Example))
# Example initialized
# True
```

As you can see it would behave very much like a unittest.MagicMock.

If there aren't any libs offering functionality like this out there I'll implement it myself but I want to be sure no one else have done this yet.

**EDIT**

I expect this proxy object to follow a through implementation [like this](https://web.archive.org/web/20230606170758/https://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/).

Comment: [`django.utils.functional.lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/utils/functional/)

Comment: @Marat This seems to suit my needs. Though there are two downsides: to use it I would need to import the whole DJango module; and their docs does not expose this piece as stable: _Most of the modules in django.utils are designed for internal use [...]_. While they specify some parts of django.utils as stable for external use, these lazy objects aren't there.

But this is a great start regardless, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Looks like the link you included has died.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund replaced the link with a Web Archive snapshot of the original page. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found module [lazy-object-proxy](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-lazy-object-proxy) which does exactly that.

Worth mentioning that as @Marat pointed out [Django offers a solution as well](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/utils/functional/), though I do not want to import Django just for that, if you're already using it in your project it will be a perfectly fine solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's Werkzeug's LocalProxy:

```
# external_module.py
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy

_internal = None

def init_value():
    global _internal
    _internal = "I'm ready now!"

proxy = LocalProxy(lambda: _internal)
```

```
# main.py
from external_module import _internal, proxy, init_value

print(_internal)   # None
print(proxy)       # None
init_value()
print(proxy)       # I'm ready now!
print(_internal)   # None
```

The lazy-loading aspect isn't covered in the [documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/local/#proxy-objects), but `LocalProxy` does what you're asking for, namely:

1. Acts as a proxy for another object
2. Defers evaluation until the object is accessed (as opposed to at import, for instance)
3. Presents itself as the proxied object (from the [documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/local/#proxy-objects)):

> "`__repr__` and `__class__` are proxied, so `repr(x)` and `isinstance(x, cls)` will look like the proxied object. Use `issubclass(type(x), LocalProxy)` to check if an object is a proxy."

```
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Example initialized")

lazy = LocalProxy(Example)              # Example initialized
print(isinstance(lazy, Example))        # True
```